# Angular8 use http2

Tags: angular, angular8, http2

I'm trying to use http2 in my angular application. So I searched and found this chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en . It indicates my site doesn't support http2. I did search on google and on official angular page and didn't found any documentation. How can I make my angular app to support http2? So far I'm using `HttpClient`. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Angular app does not need to support HTTP/2, your web browser and server need to support this. When that happens the Angular app will automatically use it as the browser will translate any `HttpClient` calls to HTTP/2 automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use http/1.1 only because users have to change their browser's settings.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are true for production environments. However, Angular's `ng serve`, which spins up a local server to serve the application in a local environment, [does not currently support HTTP2](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21293).

It seems the Angular team would like to support HTTP2 in their dev server, but they are blocked by a dependent package, Express, which [does not support HTTP2](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2761) despite 7 years of suggestions and complaints from their users.

Answer (score 0):

There are no browser settings that need to be set.  All modern browsers support http/2 by default.  The place you need to actually configure http/2 is on the backend.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to add anything new to the previous answer from a few years ago.